# Bigger border circle and center content

Tags: html, css

hey guys im already done with the front of my new website. the online problem that i have is that , i would like to have the letters a little bit bigger

```
.horizontal-list-item .photo-count{
   color: #bdbcbc;
   border-color:#bdbcbc!important;
   font-size:40px!important;
   font-family:pirulen
}
```

i gaved them this new font size. the problem is that i cant get the circle bigger so that it fits again, and the letter should be in the center of the circle  hope ya can help me out

```
<section class="horizontal-list-item" style="background-image:url(images/bg.png);">
   <div class="color-overlay" ></div>
   <div class="gallery-info">
      <div class="gallery-title"><h2>Apps</h2></div>
      <div class="photo-count">A</div>
      <div class="gallery-description"></div>
   </div>
</section>
```

here is the link i created a subdomain to upload [demo site](http://neu.awesom-media.de/)

Comment: Please tidy and format your code :)

Comment: take a look at line 1292 of `startpage.css`

Answer (score 0):

The circle dimensions are being created by the height and width of `.gallery-info .photo-count`. Therefore, all you need to do is adjust those and have the values uniform (including `border-radius` since that is a factor in the circular element) to make them bigger. From there, you would adjust the `padding` value (the first integer is for top padding) as desired to push down the text so it appears centered.

Example:

```
.gallery-info .photo-count {
border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
border-radius: 110px; /*change this */
font-size: 20px !important;
padding: 40px 0 0; /*change this */
top: 0;
display: block;
height: 110px; /*change this */
line-height: 65px;
margin: 0 auto;
opacity: 1;
position: absolute;
right: 50%;
text-align: center;
width: 110px; /*change this */
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
-webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(50%);
-ms-transform: translateX(50%);
-o-transform: translateX(50%);
transform: translateX(50%);
}
```